# API Error code Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, youtube-data-api

```
var API_KEY= 'XXX';
CHANNEL_ID = 'XXX';
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', { part: 'snippet', channelId: CHANNEL_ID, type: 'video', eventType: 'live', key: API_KEY }, function(data) {
    try {
        if(data['items'].length > 0) 
    res.json({status: true});
    }
      catch (err) {
          res.json({status: false});
          console.log(err)
        }
    });
});

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api check\server.js:24:21)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api     check\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.start (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api     check\node_modules\request\request.js:749:10)
    at Request.end (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api     check\node_modules\request\request.js:1506:10)
    at end (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api check\node_modules\request\request.js:560:14)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Own api check\node_modules\request\request.js:574:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
```

Full code :

- I'm trying to create an API that will read the YouTube data and write
  to me   on my site that if that person is in the heart or not but it
  always gives me   such a error

  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var request = require('request');

  ```
  //Configure app to use bodyParser();
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extend: true}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

  //Routes for the API
  var router = express.Router();
  router.use(function(req, res, next) {
      console.log("Got Request"); // -> Something is happening
      next();
  })

  var API_KEY= '';
  CHANNEL_ID = 'UCmDM6zuSTROOnZnjlt2RJGQ';
  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', { part:         'snippet', channelId: CHANNEL_ID, type: 'video', eventType: 'live', key: API_KEY         }, function(data) {
      try {
          if(data['items'].length > 0) 
      res.json({status: true});
      }
        catch (err) {
            res.json({status: false});
            console.log(err)
      }
  });
  });

  //Custom URL e.g. example.com:1337/api/ECHO

  router.route('/:echo').get(function(req, res) {

      res.json({echo: req.params.echo});
  })



  //All routes will be prefixed with /api
  app.use('/api', router);


  //Start the server
  app.listen(port);
  console.log('API server has been started on port ' + port);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line

```
if(data['items'].length > 0)
```

The data object does not have a property of 'items'. Do a console.log of the data object to see what is returned. It looks like the Youtube API is not called correctly and returning an error instead.

Try the following code in your request instead:

```
request({url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?",
         qs:{ 
              part: 'snippet', 
              channelId: CHANNEL_ID, 
              type: 'video', 
              eventType: 'live', 
              key: API_KEY
            }
}, function(err, response, data){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(data);
    if(data['items'].length > 0) {
        res.json({status: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: this is line 24 
    if(data['items'].length > 0)

Comment: @mlgtour is there a line where you reference the snippet property?

Comment: added server.js

Comment: It doesn't look like the error matches your code. Can you confirm that this error is happening with the version of the code you posted?

Comment: added console.log(data)
    Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: You need to replace the request call

Comment: still give me same error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: what data was in the console before the error? Please give more information to make it easier to help you.

Comment: API server has been started on port 1337
Got Request
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: That probably means no data is returned from the API, as no error was logged to console in console.log(err) and no data was logged to console in console.log(data)

Comment: so what i need to do

Comment: Read the google apis documentation here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs